# Spring-Data does not find IndexFields for Indices created via MongoDB shell

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, indexing

we are using Spring-Data-Mongo to access our MongoDB from a Java application. In general, everything works fine but I encountered one odd behavior.

When initializing our Repositories in the Java code we use ensureIndex to create indices on the collections. In a unit test we read all indices from the collections as IndexInfo objects and check if those IndexInfo objects contain the fields we want to index in the member indexFields. This also worked fine when we set everything up.

Now it happened that we had to recreate one of the indices on our production environment, so we dropped it and created it again using the Mongo shell. The system seems to run fine and no issues came up. For consistency reasons we then made the same change to our test and even local environments in the same way. Then we noticed that our unit test for index checking fails because the indexField member is now empty.

I tried everything I can imagine but as soon as I create an index using the Mongo shell Spring does not deliver any index fields anymore even when I create an index with the identical configuration.

Can anyone tell me why that happens and if that indicates there is a problem? Is there a way to fix this without having to drop the collection? I was thinking about dropping the index after our next production release and then trigger an insert. On my local machine this created the index the way I expected it and the test succeeds.

---- Additional info -----

Hi Trisha,

sorry for not acting sooner but I just got time to build a small unit test for this.

If you run the following test on an empty db it works fine:

```
@Test
public void testIndexing() throws Exception {

    this.mongoTemplate.indexOps("testcollection").ensureIndex(
        new Index().on("indexfield", Order.ASCENDING).unique().sparse());

    List<IndexInfo> indexInfos = mongoTemplate.indexOps("testcollection").getIndexInfo();

    assertEquals("We want two indexes, id and indexfield", 2, indexInfos.size());

    for (IndexInfo info : indexInfos) {
        assertEquals("All indexes are only meant to have one field", 1, info.getIndexFields().size());

        if (info.getName().startsWith("indexfield")) {
            assertTrue("Unexpected index field", info.isIndexForFields(Arrays.asList(new String[]{ "indexfield" })));
            assertTrue("Index indexfield must be unique", info.isUnique());
            assertTrue("Index indexfield must be sparse", info.isSparse());
            assertFalse("Index indexfield must not be droping duplicates", info.isDropDuplicates());
        } else if (!"_id_".equals(info.getName())) {
            fail("Unexpected index: '" + info.getName() + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Then open the mongo shell and call:

```
db.testcollection.dropIndexes();

db.testcollection.ensureIndex({"indexfield":1}, {"unique":true, "sparse":true})
```

The second call should create exactly the same index as the java code did. Now if you run the test again, the ensureIndex-Method does nothing because an index is already there (as it should, I guess) but the test fails on the assert for the index fields. The first assert works fine because the index info is there.

Checking the indexes in the mongo shell produces the same output no matter if the index was created via shell or via java code but spring does not get the index fields for some reason when the index is created via shell.

It would be really cool if you could give me a hint on this.

Comment: How are you calling ensureIndex in your code? And which version of spring data are you using?

Comment: We call the following code: this.mongoTemplate.indexOps("mycollection").ensureIndex(
            new Index().on("indexfield", Order.ASCENDING).unique().sparse()); And the version of spring-data-mongo is 1.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer as your test let me reproduce the issue.

Comment: Finally got around to post this in the Spring JIRA: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your updated question I was able to reproduce your problem.  I finally tracked down the issue to a misunderstanding between how MongoDB stores the index information and how SpringData is expecting it.

When you create an index using the following:

```
db.testcollection.ensureIndex({"indexfield":1}, {"unique":true, "sparse":true})
```

under the covers it stores the index as:

```
{
   "v" : 1,
   "key" : {
     "indexfield" : 1
   },
   "unique" : true,
   "ns" : "TheDatabase.testcollection",
   "name" : "indexfield_1",
   "sparse" : true
}
```

However, by default MongoDB treats all numbers as floating point, therefore it's secretly thinking of this as

```
   "key" : {
     "indexfield" : 1.0
   },
```

SpringData is expecting this value as an integer, however, as this is how it creates the index values it saves, and so it cannot correctly parse an index created in the shell (incidentally, this means that Geo indexes create in the shell will be parsed fine by SpringData as these are stored as Strings).

I would recommend reporting this to the guys at Spring, you will not be the only one who experiences this. I found the problem in `DefaultIndexOperations` lines 138 - 141 in version 1.1.1 of spring-data-mongodb.

However you'll be pleased to hear there is a workaround.  You can force your command on the shell to store the value as an integer (so Spring can correctly parse the index) using the following command:

```
db.testcollection.ensureIndex({indexfield: NumberInt(1) }, {unique:true, sparse:true})
```

It's a bit clumsy, but when I followed your steps but applied this command in the shell the test passed.

Comment: Is there a reason they need to be float if the only reasonable values are 1 and -1? Beyond that, the reference documentation clearly states integers to be returned for the relevant keys (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/#db.collection.getIndexes). Do you want me to file a ticket for that?

Comment: They don't need to be floats, but the code does need to understand that the Java driver will return anything that's float-ish as a double - at the deserialisation level it doesn't know that that field will always be an int, all it sees is the double.  It would be great if you could file a ticket - it's fine if you truncate to an int but it will always come back as a double.